# How use linq multi list criteria?

Tags: c#, list, linq, api, asp.net-core

i want order multi list according to the condition by use other api.

Result (i use from other api)

```
{
    "returned_data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "firstName": "FirstNameAA",
                "lastName": "LastNameAA",
                "product": [
                    {
                        "license": "1AS131",
                        "carType": "478",
                        "contract": "0112345",
                        "amounttoCurrent": 3000
                    }               
                ]
            },
            {
                "firstName": "FirstNameAA",
                "lastName": "LastNameAA",
                "product": [
                    {
                        "license": "2AS345",
                        "carType": "465",
                        "contract": "10234521",
                        "amounttoCurrent": 12000
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "firstName": "FirstNameBB",
                "lastName": "LastNameBB",
                "product": [
                    {
                        "license": "kdf9034",
                        "carType": "4234",
                        "contract": "8995412",
                        "amounttoCurrent": 1000
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**But I want to new result, new order each list by "firstName"**

```
{
    "returned_data": {
        "data": [
            {
                "firstName": "FirstNameAA",
                "lastName": "LastNameAA",
                "product": [
                    {
                        "license": "1AS131",
                        "carType": "478",
                        "contract": "0112345",
                        "amounttoCurrent": 3000
                    },
                    {
                        "license": "2AS345",
                        "carType": "465",
                        "contract": "10234521",
                        "amounttoCurrent": 12000
                    }
                ]
            },            
            {
                "firstName": "FirstNameBB",
                "lastName": "LastNameBB",
                "product": [
                    {
                        "license": "kdf9034",
                        "carType": "4234",
                        "contract": "8995412",
                        "amounttoCurrent": 1000
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Code c#**

```
var newResult = resReturnListData.returned_data.data.GroupBy(x => x.firstName);  >>> not work.
```

Please help me. thanks in advane.

Comment: Could you please show your classes for your json?

Comment: is it a compile-time error or you are not getting any result in newResult object?

Comment: If you want to order items then your linq should show an `OrderBy`. Please show what you have tried for ordering.

Comment: What does not work? You can't convert your json to classes, or can't you convert your converted classes to your desired results?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use proper group by and then select only `product` from group by result,

```
var newResult = resReturnListData.returned_data.data
    .GroupBy(x => x.firstName)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        firstName = g.Key,
        lastName = g.Select(x => x.lastName).FirstOrDefault(),
        product = g.SelectMany(x => x.product).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

If you want to group by your data with `firstName` and `lastName` then,

```
var newResult = resReturnListData.returned_data.data
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.firstName, x.lastName })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        firstName = g.Key.firstName,
        lastName = g.Key.lastName,
        product = g.SelectMany(x => x.product).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

**Usage:**

```
string json = "Your json here";

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

RootObject resReturnListData = jObject.ToObject<RootObject>();

jObject["returned_data"]["data"] = JToken.FromObject(newResult);  //<= newResult comes from either one of above linq group by result

string newJson = jObject.ToString();

Console.WriteLine(newJson);
```

**Output:** (From Console)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data structures are as follows,

```
public class Product
{
    public string license { get; set; }
    public string carType { get; set; }
    public string contract { get; set; }
    public int amounttoCurrent { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string lastName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> product { get; set; }
}

public class ReturnedData
{
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public ReturnedData returned_data { get; set; }
}
```

You can GroupBy to get the "data" result, and then, wrap it around using an anonymous object.

```
var resReturnListData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString);
var newResult = resReturnListData.returned_data.data
                .GroupBy(x => x.firstName)
                .Select(x => new Datum
                {
                    firstName = x.Key,
                    lastName = x.Select(c => c.lastName).FirstOrDefault(),
                    product = x.SelectMany(c => c.product).ToList()

                });

var finalObject = new RootObject
{
    returned_data = new ReturnedData
    {
        data = newResult.ToList()
    }
};

var jsonResult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(finalObject,Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

Output Sample,

```
{
  "returned_data": {
    "data": [
      {
        "firstName": "FirstNameAA",
        "lastName": "LastNameAA",
        "product": [
          {
            "license": "1AS131",
            "carType": "478",
            "contract": "0112345",
            "amounttoCurrent": 3000
          },
          {
            "license": "2AS345",
            "carType": "465",
            "contract": "10234521",
            "amounttoCurrent": 12000
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "firstName": "FirstNameBB",
        "lastName": "LastNameBB",
        "product": [
          {
            "license": "kdf9034",
            "carType": "4234",
            "contract": "8995412",
            "amounttoCurrent": 1000
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```